# Error while converting Farpoint spreadsheet control member code to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I am upgrading code from VB 6 to VB.NET, and the following code gives me an error:

`Col is not member of control`

Likewise it's throwing the same error for all members (row,action etc..)

```
Private Sub VGILeaveCell(ByRef sprIn As System.Windows.Forms.Control, 
ByVal lngCol As Integer, ByVal lngRow As Integer, 
ByVal lngNewCol As Integer, ByVal lngNewRow As Integer)

    '
    ' Check to see if location of new cell is locked
    '

    sprIn.col
    sprIn.Row = lngNewRow        
    sprIn.Col = lngNewCol
    '
    ' If it is locked, set the active cell back to where it was before
    '

    If sprIn.Lock Then          
        sprIn.Row = lngRow

        sprIn.Col = lngCol          
        sprIn.Action = enmVGIAction.SS_ACTION_ACTIVE_CELL
        '
        ' If it is not locked, allow the movement to proceed
        '
    Else

        sprIn.Row = lngNewRow           
        sprIn.Col = lngNewCol           
        sprIn.Action = enmVGIAction.SS_ACTION_ACTIVE_CELL
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the type of sprIn? Is it some kind of DataGrid?

Comment: Control is a specific base type.  It wont match Sprin.  Whatever type it is use that in the method sig

Comment: Not entirely helpful, but my vote is rewrite this from scratch rather than import old VB code.   Use the source as a road map in some cases, but don't be afraid to embrace newer approaches.  I would bet you'll end up with much less technical debt in the long run.

Comment: @Han   Please find the details  about sprln.. it is inst spread(FarPoint) version 3 features.      Sorry forgot to mention this important point.                                                                   VGILeaveCell(sprSpread, lngAltCol, lngAltRow, lngNewCol, lngNewRow)  
 Friend WithEvents sprSpread As AxFPSpread.AxvaSpread

Comment: `sprIn.col` makes no sense, delete that.

Answer (score 0):

First, unless you use late binding you need to assign sprIn to a variable of the correct type, and then use that variable instead of sprIn (alternatively you could change the method signature to the correct type).  We can’t know what that type is, so no working sample code. This is the best we can do without knowing the type.  First make sure Option Infer On is set either for that file or the project, then...

```
Dim newSprd = trycast(sprIn, TheCorrectFarSpreadType)
```

You can then replace all usages except for the one in the method signature and the above line, with newSprd.

Secondly, sprIn is declared as ByRef, but shouldn’t be.  It’s neither assigned a new value or passed byref to a method that assigns a new value.

Finally, I know I mentioned late binding as an alternative to getting the type right, but late binding should be reserved for situations where you need duck typing.  Given that this is an event that is being hit, that isn’t the case here.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention important point about sprln. Please find the details .. it is an inst spread(FarPoint) version 3 features. VGILeaveCell(sprSpread, lngAltCol, lngAltRow, lngNewCol, lngNewRow) Friend WithEvents sprSpread As AxFPSpread.AxvaSpread